# Pass results from a MySQL procedure to the Linux command line

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, command-line

I have a procedure which runs the following select:

```
select distinct concat( 'php /home/rudyerd-systems/frontend/ClientStatementGenerator.php ', left(user(), locate('@',user())-1), space(1), ca.client_id, space(1), date_format( @pTradingPeriodMonth, '%y%m' ), space(1), date_format( @pTradingPeriodMonth, '%y%m' ),
                    ' > /home/rudyerd-systems.sco/frontend/bash/new_statement_test.html' )
from   ca_client_account ca,
       ca_tranche tr
where  @pTradingPeriodMonth    between tr.dt_value and ifnull( tr.dt_withdrawal, @pTradingPeriodMonth ) and
       ca.client_account_id   = tr.client_account_id
order  by ca.client_id;
```

and produces the following results:

```
| php /home/rudyerd-systems/frontend/ClientStatementGenerator.php scorbet ATP 1205 1205 > /home/rudyerd-systems.sco/frontend/bash/new_statement_test.html                                                                                                          |
| php /home/rudyerd-systems/frontend/ClientStatementGenerator.php scorbet BLB 1205 1205 > /home/rudyerd-systems.sco/frontend/bash/new_statement_test.html                                                                                                          |
| php /home/rudyerd-systems/frontend/ClientStatementGenerator.php scorbet CAR 1205 1205 > /home/rudyerd-systems.sco/frontend/bash/new_statement_test.html                                                                                                          |
| php /home/rudyerd-systems/frontend/ClientStatementGenerator.php scorbet CDR 1205 1205 > /home/rudyerd-systems.sco/frontend/bash/new_statement_test.html                                                                                                          |
| php /home/rudyerd-systems/frontend/ClientStatementGenerator.php scorbet CSP 1205 1205 > /home/rudyerd-systems.sco/frontend/bash/new_statement_test.html                                                                                                          |
| php /home/rudyerd-systems/frontend/ClientStatementGenerator.php scorbet DGC 1205 1205 > /home/rudyerd-systems.sco/frontend/bash/new_statement_test.html                                                                                                          |
| php /home/rudyerd-systems/frontend/ClientStatementGenerator.php scorbet FDR 1205 1205 > /home/rudyerd-systems.sco/frontend/bash/new_statement_test.html                                                                                                          |
| php /home/rudyerd-systems/frontend/ClientStatementGenerator.php scorbet FVN 1205 1205 > /home/rudyerd-systems.sco/frontend/bash/new_statement_test.html                                                                                                          |
| php /home/rudyerd-systems/frontend/ClientStatementGenerator.php scorbet JLM 1205 1205 > /home/rudyerd-systems.sco/frontend/bash/new_statement_test.html                                                                                                          |
| php /home/rudyerd-systems/frontend/ClientStatementGenerator.php scorbet JRA 1205 1205 > /home/rudyerd-systems.sco/frontend/bash/new_statement_test.html                                                                                                          |
| php /home/rudyerd-systems/frontend/ClientStatementGenerator.php scorbet JRP 1205 1205 > /home/rudyerd-systems.sco/frontend/bash/new_statement_test.html                                                                                                          |
| php /home/rudyerd-systems/frontend/ClientStatementGenerator.php scorbet MJO 1205 1205 > /home/rudyerd-systems.sco/frontend/bash/new_statement_test.html                                                                                                          |
| php /home/rudyerd-systems/frontend/ClientStatementGenerator.php scorbet MPW 1205 1205 > /home/rudyerd-systems.sco/frontend/bash/new_statement_test.html                                                                                                          |
| php /home/rudyerd-systems/frontend/ClientStatementGenerator.php scorbet NTC 1205 1205 > /home/rudyerd-systems.sco/frontend/bash/new_statement_test.html                                                                                                          |
| php /home/rudyerd-systems/frontend/ClientStatementGenerator.php scorbet RJA 1205 1205 > /home/rudyerd-systems.sco/frontend/bash/new_statement_test.html                                                                                                          |
| php /home/rudyerd-systems/frontend/ClientStatementGenerator.php scorbet RMM 1205 1205 > /home/rudyerd-systems.sco/frontend/bash/new_statement_test.html                                                                                                          |
| php /home/rudyerd-systems/frontend/ClientStatementGenerator.php scorbet SJC 1205 1205 > /home/rudyerd-systems.sco/frontend/bash/new_statement_test.html                                                                                                          |
| php /home/rudyerd-systems/frontend/ClientStatementGenerator.php scorbet UDB 1205 1205 > /home/rudyerd-systems.sco/frontend/bash/new_statement_test.html
```

I would like to output the results from the procedure directly to the Linux command line so that a HTML page with each of the variables is created. This procedure will be run from a bash script within the folder in which I would like to create the HTML files.

For Completeness this is the complete procedure.

```
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- pUIGetCliStmtGenList
--
-- This procedure returns the Clients who statements need to be generated for
--
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

drop procedure if exists pUiGetCliStmtGenList;
delimiter //

create procedure pUiGetCliStmtGenList(
  IN  pTradingPeriodMonth      DATE,
  IN  pUsername                VARCHAR,
  IN  pPassword                VARCHAR,
  OUT pResult                  INT
)
MODIFIES SQL DATA
COMMENT 'Gathers the list of people a statement needs to be created for'
begin
 --
  declare vClient_id           VARCHAR(3);
  declare vAmtTradedSystemCcy  DECIMAL(13,2);
  declare vCount               INT;
  --
  declare EXIT handler for SQLWARNING, SQLEXCEPTION call pRdHandleError( 10000, 'pUiGetCliStmtGenList', vHint );
  --  ***********************************************************************************************************
  set vHint = pTradingPeriodMonth;
  set pResult = 0;

  SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT( 'php /home/rudyerd-systems/frontend/ClientStatementGenerator.php ', left(user(), locate('@',user())-1), space(1), ca.client_id, space(1), date_format( @pTradingPeriod, '%y%m' ), space(1), date_format( @pTradingPeriod, '%y%m' ),
                    ' > /home/rudyerd-systems.sco/frontend/bash/'ca.client_id''@pTradingPeriod'statement.html' )
  FROM   ca_client_account ca,
         ca_tranche tr
  INTO     
  WHERE  @pTradingPeriodMonth    between tr.dt_value and ifnull( tr.dt_withdrawal, @pTradingPeriodMonth ) and
         ca.client_account_id   = tr.client_account_id
  ORDER BY ca.client_id;
  --
  -- If there are no clients
    if vCount <> 0 then
     call pRdHandleError( 1002, 'pUiGetCliStmtGenFlag', vHint );
    end if; 
  --
  --   
  ELSE
  -- Output to Linux Command Line and Generate the HTML pages

  -- Then Convert the pages to pdf
  -- 
  set pResult = 1;
  --
end;
//

delimiter ;
```

Comment: It's not clear what the filenames are supposed to be or what their contents are or whether the output shown is intended to be a runnable script with the redirection which is apparently specified. If it's supposed to be runnable, then the same file would get repeatedly overwritten (unless you change the `>` to `>>`). I don't see where the pipe characters come from. You need to much more clearly specify what you want.

Comment: Sorry Dennis, the new_statement_test.html will be prefixed by the 3 letter client ID to produce unique filenames. ie SJC_new_statement_test.html. All I want to do is run each of the lines above through the linux command line generating an html page for each client

Comment: I have written an answer on that basis.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the output show is intended to be a runnable script and that you change the `>` to `>>` or add one of the field values to the output filename so that they're unique, this *might* be what you're after:

```
mysql -B -u username -p dbname < script.sql | sed 's/|//' | sh
```

the `sed` command removes the pipe character if it's present. Piping the whole thing through `sh` executes each line running `php` with the given arguments and redirecting the output to the given file. You may need to change the `mysql` arguments to suit your needs.

Comment: Hi Dennis, thank you for that. I have added the full proceedure above. I will call this from the bash script and need the results to be output to the command line. I hope this makes more sense not I have provide the full code. Many thanks for your help

Comment: @SamCorbet: You don't show how your Bash script calls it. The `mysql` command I show is a standin for what my assumption of that would be. Regardless, all you need to do is pipe the output into `sh` (and possibly the `sed` command to get rid of the pipe character). In what way does my answer not work?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the server, so that you can create files, you're able to export the output in CSV file like:

```
SELECT field1,field2 FROM table1
INTO OUTFILE '/home/output.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

You can than write parser or modify the entries using another scripting language/tools to suit your needs...